# Load iFrame contents via CURL request?

Tags: php, iframe, curl

I have an application that includes a file (FileX.php) which under certain conditions, will echo an iFrame to the screen which loads a tracking URL (FileY.php). In a production environment where I directly include FileX.php into the main page (FileA.php), the iFrame gets echoed to the screen and FileY.php is successfully called.

In testing though, I need to call multiple versions of FileA.php which each include FileX.php which outputs the iFrame to call FileY.php. I am automating this large number of requests using cURL requests.

When loading FileA.php through a cURL request, it successfully does the `include()` of FileX.php but because it is happening through cURL, the iFrame never loads it's destination (FileY.php).

The cURL request for fileA looks something like this:

**TestFile.php**

```
// URL
$url = "http://www.example.com/FileA.php";

// New Cookie file
$ckfile = tempnam("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");

// New Connection
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

**FileA.php:**

```
include_once('FileX.php');
```

**FileX.php:**

```
echo("<iframe src='http://www.example.com/FileY.php' width='0' height='0'></iframe>");
```

**FileY.php**

```
// Contains logging stuff to log the fact that FileY.php was called.
```

Like I said, if I call FileA.php directly in my browser, FileX.php is included and FileY.php is loaded in the iFrame successfully. When I call FileA.php via cURL the iFrame doesn't load and FileY.php is never called.

I've tried wrapping the `echo()` in FileX.php with `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()` to force the output but that didn't work. I've tried adding a `sleep(1)` in case maybe the request was happening too fast, no luck.

Is there a cURL option I can change to allow this to occur? I can't figure out why it won't load the iFrame src.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, so it turns out I was using an option incorrectly.

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

This should actually be `false` or `0`. When using `true` or `1`, all output is caught and returned via the cURL request rather than being output. So it should be:

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
```